# If $\{a_n\}$ is a positive, nonincreasing sequence such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges, then prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}2^na_{2^n} = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification

> If $\{a_n\}$ is a positive, nonincreasing sequence such that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges, then use the following theorem to prove that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}2^na_{2^n} = 0:$$ **THEOREM (2nd part of Cauchy Condensation Test)**: If $\{a_n\}$ is a nonincreasing sequence of positive numbers and if $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty2^na_{2^n}$ diverges, then $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ diverges.

Something leads me to believe that the theorem the problem refers to might be a typo (my textbook refers to the theorem by number--it doesn't explicitly write it out). If the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges, then the Cauchy Condensation Test would say that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^na_{2^n}$ converges, no? (because the Cauchy Condensation Test can't say that if the condensed series diverges, then the original series converges). Then by the $n^{th}$-term test, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}2^na_{2^n} = 0.$$

Am I missing something here? Or is *this* how it is intended to be used--that the original series converged, so the condensed series cannot diverge by the (2nd part of) Cauchy Condensation Test and thus must converge. So $\lim_{n\to\infty}2^na_{2^n} = 0.$

Comment: "$A$ diverges $\Rightarrow$ $B$ diverges" is equivalent to "$B$ converges $\Rightarrow$ $A$ converges". Just apply negation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the Cauchy condensation test we have
$$
\bigg(\sum_{n=0}^\infty2^na_{2^n} \text{ diverges } \Rightarrow \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\text{ diverges } \bigg) \Longleftrightarrow 
\bigg( \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\text{ converges } \Rightarrow \sum_{n=0}^\infty2^na_{2^n}\text{ converges } \bigg)
$$
for positive and non-increasing sequences $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$. If you assume that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges this implies that also $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2^n a_{2^n}$ converges and hence $\lim_{n \to \infty} 2^n a_{2^n}=0$.